# Setting a dynamic favicon for IE9 from the controller (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-9, favicon

I am struggling to have the favicon set dynamically (using the controller) on IE9. If I just hardcode the link like this, it works and I see the favicon:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/folder/fav.ico"/>
```

But trying to do it dynamically, it won't work:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{url}}"/>
```

`url` is set in my controller like so:

```
$rootScope.url= '/folder/fav.ico'
```

If I try a `console.log($rootScope.url)` or if I have `{{url}}` in the **body** of my HTML document, I get the right value. This means that I either:

1. don't get the `{{url}}` value inside the `<head>` at all
2. can't have Angular variables inside the `<link>`

Please note that I also have a dynamic `<title>` set in the same controller and it works fine. This means that the controller is fine.

Do you have any ideas on how to either fix or debug this thing?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not considered best practice, but I think for IE9 and 10 to understand it, you might need to change it like the sample mathiasbynens has written here:
https://gist.github.com/mathiasbynens/428626

I think the element has to be removed and appended again, for IE to notice the change.